# Unable to achieve Secure connection to redis container through Ngnix using SSL

Tags: azure, docker, redis, containers, azure-container-instances

[Secure connection to redis container through Ngnix using SSL using RDM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727340/secure-connection-to-redis-container-through-ngnix-using-ssl-using-rdm)

Please refer this question for details. I have exact same scenario and unable to achieve using nginx or stunnel.

Below is the issue with Nginx.

[image: Error]

When I call from browser redis is blocking, so SSL is working fine. But when I am connecting through redis-cli, I am getting below error.

[image: Error]

Below is the issue with Stunnel.

[image: Stunnel]

I see peer is getting disconnected for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have just answered in that post. The key pointed is to add your self-signed to trusted store.

[image]

For more details, please refer to my answer to previous question. Duo to the forum policy, I cannot add the same answer here.

Comment: I have added more description, could you please look into it.

Comment: Have you specified the private key in redis cli?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Do we need to pass as parameter while connecting through redis-cli?

Comment: Tcp SSL termination is not supported in nginx but it is supported in Nginx Plus.